# How to install applications on azure VM

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM and IIS setup through ADO playbook. Is it possible to have the playbook also install applications like putty as well? I’m using ansible as well in the playbook.

I thought I might be able to use get_url but that will just download the installer.

If there is no way, then is the best practice to just build up the VM the way I need it and to create an image?

Comment: what is ado playbook? you can use vm script\dsc extension to install those or just use ansible to configure the vm

Answer (score 0):

You could likely find a way to install programs using something like Custom Script Extension or manually modifying the install files to skip any user input. That being said, the best option would be to create an image with the required programs already installed then capture an image of that VM. This will save you a lot of time and effort so I suggest simply going that route instead.